# Question active contour model energy function

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

I have hard to understand how snake energy function.

$$E_{\mathrm{smade}}^{*}=\int_{0}^{1}E_{\mathrm{suake}}(\mathbf{v}(s)),d s=\int_{0}^{1}(E_{\mathrm{imteral}}(\mathbf{v}(s))+E_{\mathrm{image}}(\mathbf{v}(s))+E_{\mathrm{con}}(\mathbf{v}(s)))d s$$

1. Why integral from 0 to 1? It looks like haveing n points of v. This parameterize to $v(s)$ and looks like $s$ is a unit length.
2. If I have picture, how to transform all pixel s to $E_{image}$ term